# jquery toggle two animations

Tags: jquery

Basically I'm trying to toggle between the two different click functions everytime you click the button.

Heres the jquery code:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("#sidebar").animate({ width: '0px' }, 250, function() {
            $(this).hide();
         });
    $("#tabs_container").animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 500);
    $("#tabs_container ul.tabs li a").animate({
        width: "247px"
    }, 500);
    $("#myElement_wrapper").animate({
        width: "970px"
    }, 500);
});
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#sidebar").show().animate({
        width: "219px"
    }, 500);
    $("#tabs_container").animate({
        width: "781px"
    }, 500);
    $("#tabs_container ul.tabs li a").animate({
        width: "190px"
    }, 500);
    $("#myElement_wrapper").animate({
        width: "720px"
    }, 500);
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's what [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) is for. Pass it those two functions you created:

```
$("button").toggle(function () {
    $("#sidebar").animate({ width: '0px' }, 250, function() {
       $(this).hide();
    });
    // the rest of your first animation sequence
}, function () {
    $("#sidebar").show().animate({
        width: "219px"
    }, 500);
    // the rest of your second animation sequence
});
```

You should also look into caching your selectors...

---

If you're using jQuery 1.9+, you'll have to keep your own flag:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var toggle = $.data(this, 'clickToggle');

    if ( toggle ) {
        // your first animation sequence
    } else {
        // your second animation sequence
    }

    $.data(this, 'clickToggle', ! toggle);
});
```

Comment: Just note that this `toggle` method which alternates click handlers has been removed from jQuery core as of jQuery 1.9.

Comment: i will investigate caching selectors! thanks again for the speedy reply :)

Comment: it seems when i replace my current code with your one, the button disappears completely. not really sure what's going on. like its there for a second and then disappears (before you can even click it).

Comment: @user1448093 - What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: latest from the google cdn. I also gave nnnnnn's solution a go and it seems to be working fine but i'd still like to understand both if possible (/if you have time)

Comment: @user1448093 - As pointed out by FabrícioMatté, jQuery 1.9 removed this usage of `toggle`. Google's CDN is serving you the latest version of jQuery, which currently is 1.9. You'd have to use nnnnnn's solution, but I'd suggest using it a little differently, as I said in the comment to his answer. I added the code to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a flag to remember whether the element is currently on the "odd" or "even" click:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        flag = $this.data("clickflag");
    if (!flag) {
        // first code here
    } else {
        // second code here
    }
    $this.data("clickflag", !flag);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KHLdr/

This uses jQuery's [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store a boolean value against the clicked element.

Comment: Instead of creating and caching the superfluos `$(this)` object, just use the static method on the jQuery namespace: `$.data(this, 'clickflag')` and `$.data(this, 'clickflag', ! flag)`. It's *much* fater.

Comment: Thanks @JosephSilber. Yes, that definitely makes sense in this case. I don't usually think of `$.data()`, probably because most of the time when I need to use `.data()` I need a `$(this)` reference to the element to do other stuff to it anyway.